# XML String en Objeto Java

Tags: java, java-ee, spring-mvc

Necesito serializar un *XML* que viene como un *String* desde un *Header* del navegador a un objeto *Java* para poder acceder a uno de sus atributos.

Lo ideal sería algo que lo genere de forma automática para no tener que crear clases que mapeen los campos del *XML*.

Si existe algo en *Spring MVC* que lo haga al recibir el valor, sería mucho mejor.

Comment: Existe, la palabra clave es marshalling. Revisa el código en la documentación de [Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/oxm.html).

Comment: Si mal no recuerdo mis épocas Javeras, esto se hace por medio de JAXB. Es muy sencillo, inténtalo y si tienes problemas, actualiza tu pregunta colocando el código que tengas.